# Why i can't watch videos? Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: firefox, video

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and i have a problem - i can't watch videos.

For example i can watch videos in youtube, but in most of the other websites i can't play the video it says "Format not supported" or "Video can't be played in this browser"

The tracking blocking is set to standart.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Run `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Answer (score 0):

Pilot6 answered in the comments, and it worked for me. Writing this just in case someone misses their comment, and has the same problem.

You can just run:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't answer the question, but it does help people who come here in the future.